In some words [ɪ] sounds a bit like [i]?
It seems to me that [ɪ] sounds a bit similar to [i] in certain words, e.g., discover, democracy, tissue.
I'm wondering: 1. for native speakers, do you feel the same? 2. if this phenomenon exists, is there any phonological explanation (phonological rule perhaps?) to it? I have a gut feeling it is affected by the consonants before and after [ɪ] in the example words.
Any idea is appreciated.

The US pronunciation of discover does seem to have a slightly fronted and/or raised /ɪ/ that is a little bit [i]-like, but the other four (= US and UK for the other two words) to me have quite clear and distinct [ɪ] sounds that don’t sound like [i] at all. There are some dialects where /ɪ/ is generally fronted and raised (e.g., Australian), but that’s not the case in the more standard UK and US recordings given on Wiktionary.

@JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the reply. It seems British accent for discover also has this phenomenon? I have a feeling it is probably not an accent thing but because the consonants [d] and [s] are both pronounced in the front, which makes [ɪ] move a bit towards the front, but I'm not sure.

That could still make it an accent thing, assimilation, like many sound changes, is a "natural" phenomenon but that doesn't mean it always occurs.
